# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable while deploying flask app using uwsgi/nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, digital-ocean, uwsgi, uwsgi-stats-server

I am deploying a flask web app using uwsgi and nginx following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) .  When I run the command  `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app` as mentioned in tutorial for testing, it gives error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable on any api requests or any end points. Although simple running `python wsgi.py` file on port 5001 , all requests return response without any error.

Code in `wsgi.py`

```
from ds_app import factory
import ds_app as app
if  __name__=="__main__":
    app = factory.create_app(celery=app.celery)
    app.run()
```

Response while running uwsgi command is below.

```
(venv_nsfw) ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-153:~/trell_projects/trell-ds-framework$ uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5001 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Jul 13 15:13:05 2020] ***
compiled with version: 7.5.0 on 24 April 2020 01:54:26
os: Linux-4.15.0-1058-aws #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 15 22:35:20 UTC 2020
nodename: ip-172-30-1-153
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/trell_projects/trell-ds-framework
detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/trell_projects/venv_nsfw/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 255081
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5001 fd 3
Python version: 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)  [GCC 8.4.0]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x5643bd9502c0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x5643bd9502c0 pid: 11035 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 11035, cores: 1)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[pid: 11035|app: 0|req: 1/1] 45.95.98.96 () {30 vars in 612 bytes} [Mon Jul 13 15:13:31 2020] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[pid: 11035|app: 0|req: 2/2] 171.51.145.232 () {32 vars in 620 bytes} [Mon Jul 13 15:14:12 2020] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can anybody help me why same code giving error while running using uWSGi command. Any leads highly appraciated.

Comment: You import `factory` from the `ds_app` module and then you import the `ds_app` module again aliasing it to `app`. You could drop the `from` statement and then use `app.factory`. You alias `ds_app` module as `app` but then create a variable called `app` (overriding the import and overring the value of `app.celery`). Neither `factory` (with `factory.create_app`) nor `app` (with `app.run`) are callable. Try `print(type(factory))` and `print(type(app))` in your code to help you understand where it's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Moving code outside  if __main__ worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving code outside  if **main** worked.

```
from ds_app import factory
import ds_app as application
app = factory.create_app(celery=application.celery)
if  __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```